# Want to write to file from android application widget, but the FileInputStream is null when accessed from the widget

Tags: java, android, widget

I am currently working on creating a widget for my application. In my application, I have a load function that writes all the previous data from a text file to create an object that remembers the user's saved date from the previous uses. When this load function is called while the app is open, it works as expected. However, when the load function is called from the widget, the FileInputStream is null. Is there any precautions I have to take to load from my widget?

```
private void load()
{

    String fileName = "locationstorage.txt";

    FileInputStream fis = null;
    try
    {
        fis = openFileInput(fileName);
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String text;

        while ((text = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(text).append("\n");
        }

        StringTokenizer nl = new StringTokenizer(sb.toString(), "\n");
        StringTokenizer colon;
        double lng, lat;
        String lbl;
        String dateInString;
        Location lo;
        LocationListItem tmp;
        Date curDt;
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");

        while(nl.hasMoreTokens())
        {
            //long lat label
            colon = new StringTokenizer(nl.nextToken(), "%");
            lng = Double.valueOf(colon.nextToken());
            lat = Double.valueOf(colon.nextToken());
            lbl = colon.nextToken();
            dateInString = colon.nextToken();
            //curDt = formatter.parse(dateInString);
            lo = new Location("");
            lo.setLongitude(lng);
            lo.setLatitude(lat);
            tmp = new LocationListItem(lo, lbl, dateInString);
            locList.add(tmp);
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally
    {
        if (fis != null) {
            try
            {
                fis.close();
            } catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the function called from clicking on my widget:

```
public void widgetSaveLocation()
{
    if(locList == null)
    {
        locList = new ArrayList<LocationListItem>();
        load(0);
    }
    Location location;
    location = new Location("");

    location.setLatitude(0);
    location.setLongitude(0);

    label = "test";
    Date date = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
    LocationListItem newItem = new LocationListItem(location, label, formatter.format(date));
    locList.add(newItem);
    saveTextAsFile(listToString());
}
```

Comment: By "widget", do you mean an [app widget](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/overview)? If so, `AppWidgetProvider` is a subclass of `BroadcastReceiver`; you should not be doing disk I/O in an `AppWidgetProvider`. Beyond that, your question says that "the FileInputStream is null", but there is no `FileInputStream` in your code.

Comment: @CommonsWare where it says "fis = openFileInput(fileName);" is where it fails to open the file. Is there a reason I should not do disk i/o from an app widget?

Comment: "where it says "fis = openFileInput(fileName);" is where it fails to open the file" -- I am sorry for missing that you had `fis` typed as `FileInputStream`! "Is there a reason I should not do disk i/o from an app widget?" -- if you do it in methods like `onUpdate()`, you are doing disk I/O on the main application thread. If you try forking a thread, your process might terminate before the I/O has completed.

Comment: @CommonsWare I have a function that is called upon clicking my widget. That is where I need to call this load function. The function is finished to completion unless I add this load function, which causes problems with i/o. The function that is called onclick of my widget is in my main activity, however.